# DOS Batch extracting block from xml file

Tags: xml, batch-file

I can't find a way to do this (Have tried searching through StackOverflow).

I have a formatted xml file, and I have to extract a block from it as-is (without modifying the format, tab, <, >, and so on..) For example, let us say there is a file called `some.xml`

The block is delimited by:

```
 <!- Let us call this tag_begin -->
 <Ask Ref_Ask="XXXYYYYY">   
   ...
 <!- Let us call this tag_end -->
 </Ask>
```

I succes to  extract begin and end lines for blockend tag, but I can't have the all lines length into the result.txt file: the lines stop at 127 chars length: what's wrong ?

```
@echo off

Set Tag_Begin="<Ask Ref_Ask="
Set Tag_End="</Ask>"
set NB=XXXYYYY
set /A CPTE=0
set Line_Begin=
set Line_End=


Rem --- Find all possible start of block lines, and extract the good one set to Line_Begin
findstr /n /C:%Tag_Begin% some.xml | find /i "%NB%"> temporary.txt
for /f "tokens=1 delims=:" %%L in (temporary.txt) do set Line_Begin=%%L

Rem --- Finding the line order (from all possible start lines) which match the good one
findstr /n /C:%Tag_Begin% some.xml | findstr /n "%NB%"> temporary.txt
for /f "tokens=1 delims=:" %%O in (temporary.txt) do set order_begin=%%O
set /A order_begin-=1


Rem -- Looking for all possible end of block lines, and extract the "order_begin" one for Line_End
for /f "skip=%order_begin% tokens=1 delims=:" %%F in ('findstr /n /C:%Tag_End% some.xml') do set Line_End=%%F & goto away
:away


setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f %%L in (some.xml) do (
set /A CPTE+=1
echo CPTE=!CPTE!
if !CPTE! GEQ %Line_Begin% if !CPTE! LEQ %Line_End% echo %%L >> result.txt
)
setlocal disabledelayedexpansion

del temporary.txt
```

Comment: @JohnSaunders - it's cooler with a batch :)

Answer (score 0):

not tested:

```
        @echo off
        for /f "tokens=1 delims=:" %%L in ('findstr /n "<!- Let us call this begin tag -->" ssome.xml') do ( 
         set begin_line=%%L
        )

        for /f "tokens=1 delims=:" %%L in ('findstr /n "<!- Let us call this end tag -->" some.xml') do ( 
         set /a end_line=%%L+1
        )

        echo showing lines between %end_line% and %begin_line%
        break>"%temp%\empty"
        fc "%temp%\empty" "some.xml" /lb  %end_line% /t |more +4 | findstr /B /E /V "*****" | more +%begin_line%
        del /Q /F "%temp%\empty"
```

Change the `some.xml` on the three places with your file.

Comment: Thank's: I will try/update it to my need and let you know asap

Comment: 3 parts:

1) find begin line
2) find end line
 then
3) extract

for 1 and 2, 1st pb is some.xml include many block of this kind:
 lot of begin tag:
     each "Ref_Ask=" have unique ref enquoted by " "
  lot of end tag:
     so there is as much end tag than begin tag

for 3), I make change to extract:
     I set myself begin_line and end_line
     use more +8 instead more+4
     have to add 7 to real end_line 

for 3), I also have a pb because the line are "cut": not line is longer than 127 chars

Before ask, I already try with setlocal regarding the "< >" probleme caused by the xml format

Comment: I've edited the answer and it's now more precise.Tested it and works.You don't need to add `setlocal` as < and > are inside quotes.But will show only the last segment ...

Answer (score 0):

This uses a helper batch file called `findrepl.bat` from - http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4697

Place `findrepl.bat` in the same folder as the batch file.

```
@echo off
type some.xml|findrepl "<Ask Ref_Ask=.XXXYYYYY.>" /e:"</Ask>" >newfile.xml
```